# Can I change my itinerary after applying for a Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, connecting-flights

I am planning to travel to Thessaloniki (Greece) from India by the end of this month. My current itinerary is as follows:

Departure: Mumbai - Qatar - Thessaloniki (Greece) [27th June]

Arrival: Thessaloniki - Amsterdam - Mumbai [1st July]

I have applied for Schengen visa from 27th June to 1st of July. My queries are as follows.

1. Can I reschedule my flight so that I will leave from India on 26th but land Greece on 27th?
2. Am I allowed to book a flight from Mumbai to Athens, visit Athens for a day and then fly to Thessaloniki? An in person visa interview at Greek embassy is coming up on monday. Currently, I have my ticket to Greece in a single PNR. If I **change the submitted itinerary** and reschedule with two flights, will that be an issue during my interview?
3. On return, I have a 12 hour layover in Amsterdam. Since I have a valid Schengen visa (hopefully!), can I visit Amsterdam for 6 hours and return to catch the connecting flight?

Comment: Here is the itinerary. https://imgur.com/WsfRnze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, that's all fine.** You're not changing the reason you're traveling, the countries you're traveling to or the dates you're arriving or leaving, so your visa remains perfectly valid, and you can definitely head into Amsterdam for a few hours during your layover.

However, just to avoid any potential for confusion, if I were you I would keep my flights as is until the interview, so what you've put in your visa application matches your itinerary exactly. Again, there's nothing *wrong* with these minor changes, you just want to avoid unnecessary questions about any discrepancies if you're asked to show your tickets.

After the interview, you can change your flights as needed.

Comment: Thanks you for your reply. My current reservation (which I submitted to VFS and has reached embassy) for departure has failed and I need to book tickets again. If I book two tickets (Mumbai to Athens, Athens to Thessaloniki), would that look weird during the interview?

Comment: @arjun.ar They don't care about your exact travel arrangements, what matters is why you're going, how you're going to fund the trip, how likely is it that you'll return etc.

Comment: I got my visa! They grilled me about my itinerary though.